# How to replace every string data in a coulmn to a default string if it dosent match the given string

Tags: string, sqlite

So in my SQLite table i have a column name Status which is a varchar(500)

I want to replace everything with "Present" if it is not equal to "Absent"

How can i do this?

I am a newbie in sql

just an example of code to explain it poperly

```
SELECT Status from NewDB
if ( Status != 'Absent'){
    replace NewDB.Status = 'Present'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the table with a where clause.

```sql
UPDATE NewDB SET Status = "Present" WHERE Status != "Absent";
```

This will update Status column with the string "Present" when it is not equal to "Absent".